# FIlter collection_select by value in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Well I have this coffeeScript:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#cmbPab').change ->
       ubis = $('#cmbUbi').html()
       pabellon = $(this).val()
       options = $('#cmbUbi').filter("FilterByValue")
```

I want it to filter options by value, I already saw railcats stuff but he filters by a different way and I need to do it by value cause value is my id

Here is the cod of both collection_select where cmbPab is my main combo:

```
        <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :Pabellon %>
         <%= f.collection_select :idubicacion, Mtopabellon.all, 
             :codpabellon, :nombre, {prompt: 'Seleccione un pabellón'}, 
             :class=>'form-control', :id => 'cmbPab'%>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :Ubicacion %>
          <%= f.collection_select :idubicacion, CrUbicacion.all, :id, 
          :nombre, {prompt: 'Seleccione una ubicación'}, :class=>'form-
          control', :id => 'cmbUbi'  %>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should add the relevant HTML to your question. What is the element with the id `cmbUbi` and what does it contain? Also, when you say filter, do you mean you wish to hide some elements or just retrieve some attributes from a subset of the elements?

Comment: cmbPab and cmbUbi are both collection_select, the cmbUbi must change the collection it have based on what item is selected on the cmbPab collection_select, so I just want to retrieve some elements to fill the combo with new content

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're after something along these lines:

```
$('#cmbPab').change ->
  displayFilterFn = (i, el) -> $(el).val() == 'something?' // do your filtering
  $ubis = $('#cmbUbi')
  $ubis.children().hide()
  $ubis.children().filter(displayFilterFn).show()
```

Without knowing the specifics of how you want to filter your options, other than that it is based on the value, I can't provide you a filtering function implementation (`displayFilterFn` above). The basic idea is to first hide all options, and then show the ones that match your filter.

For more info on the `.filter()`, see the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Thanks, at the end I did it by ajax to a controller method, ill leave the solution answer, anyway thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer guys! I think this is the best way to do it, maybe not the easier but it works!

https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/